# The breakpoint will not currently be hit wcf service. Can not load symbols

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, visual-studio, debugging

Ok I have solution with 2 projects. One WPF client app and the other WCF service app. I get this annoying error while debugging wcf service: “The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document”. Now I know this is well known problem, so I tried different solutions for this problem but none of this works for me:

- I checked my debug mode, and it is not Release it is set to Debug
- I checked wcf web.config file and debugging is set to true
- I tried debug-windows-modules to browse my .pdb file but my wcf dll was not in the list
- I completely deleted bin and obj folders and rebuild my projects but still breakpoint doesn't work
- I unchecked option "Just my code" in debug options and settings menu
- Set my solution to start multiple projects.

So none of this worked for me. I wonder is there any other solutions for this problem becouse this really annoys me and took me like 2 days now. Does anyone have any suggestinos what could couse this problem?

Comment: Eventually I had to move my wcf service project to another solution and I was then able to debug with two instances of visual studio running. Not a solution for the problem but that's all I came out with.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I suggest before trying any solutions above please **make sure that you install ASP.NET and web development package from visual studio installer.**
I spend many hours thinking why my debug symbols in WCF are not hit. Finally, I found that I forgot to install this package.

[visual studio installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/347f2.png)

Answer (score 1):

As Vachirakorn Rungsikawanich said, it is **very** important that you have "windows communication foundation" package from "ASP.NET and web development" checked in the installation.

It seems the package is optional in the installation, so if you (or someone who installed it) didn't pay attention, none of the solutions you try will work. [image: sdf]

Answer (score 0):

Remove /bin and /obj folders manually (i.e: from File Explorer) and rebuild the project.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2019-->Tools-->Debugging-->General Check **Enable .NET Framework source stepping** option
[Click here for image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiYmV.png)